# Skipping the middle mapping with cryptsetup luksOpen

Tags: linux, devices, device-mapper

I'm mounting a bunch of encrypted disks like so

```
cryptsetup luksOpen some_source some_mapping &&
mount /dev/mapper/some_mapping /some_mountpoint
```

How can I abstract away the middle mapping?

I suppose I could do something like:

```
uuid=$(sudo some_device |head -n1)
some_mapping=$uuid
 cryptsetup luksOpen some_source $some_mapping &&
    mount /dev/mapper/$some_mapping /some_mountpoint
```

and put this in a script.

Is there a better way?
Can I also make sure that `umount`ing
automatically removes the middle mapping?

Answer (score 1):

Yah I use scripts for that because I also grow my encripted volumes with LVM sometimes. I use a script like this;

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
trap 'echo "ERROR: $BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO $BASH_COMMAND" >&2' ERR

M="$1"
C=$(mount | grep -c "$M" || true)
if [ "$C" -gt 0 ] ; then
    echo "/media/$M already mounted" >&2
    exit 1
fi
vgimport "vg_$M"
vgchange -ay "vg_$M"
cryptsetup luksOpen "/dev/vg_$M/lv_$M" "crypt_$M"
if [ ! -d "/media/$M" ] ; then
    mkdir "/media/$M"
fi
mount "/dev/mapper/crypt_$M" "/media/$M"
```

Comment: I never seem to need the vgimport/vchange commands. My vg mappings seem to be always even in initramfs. IDK why. Anyway, thanks for the inspiration.

Comment: @PSkocik I use VG import/export because these particular drives are detached from the system and one would not want to detach them without first making absolutely sure they are not in use.

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
   mount the_encrypted_lv the_mount_point
```

and it asked for a password and correctly decrypted and mounted the volume.

`mount` then showed the mountpoint and an autogenerated intemmediary mapping.
`umount` then removed both.

Sometimes the naive thing works.